# Travis-CI - configure LLVM

Tags: llvm, travis-ci

Is there any guide how to configure the .yml file on the Travis to get the LLVM >= 3.8?

This is the part of the Makefile that I'm using to compile my program:

```
all: program

OBJS = obj1.o obj2.o obj3.o obj4.o

CPPFL = `llvm-config --cppflags` -std=c++11
LDFL = `llvm-config --ldflags` -lpthread -ldl -lz -lncurses -rdynamic
LIBS = `llvm-config --libs`

program: $(OBJS)
    g++ -o $@ $(OBJS) $(LIBS) $(LDFL)

%.o: %.cpp
    g++ -c $(CPPFL) -o $@ $<
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I haven't done this myself yet, but I think for Mac OS machine it is about installing the latest `brew install llvm` or  3.9 `brew install llvm@3.9` to its default location `/usr/local/opt/llvm` and referencing all tools you need there.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5959) is still an open issue.

The most relevant examples I could find to help are [this](https://genbattle.bitbucket.io/blog/2016/01/17/c++-travis-ci/) and [this](https://github.com/scrossuk/locic/blob/master/.travis.yml).
So yeah, you basically need to set up the specific toolchain yourself on the Travis VM.

PS: I could have added this as a comment, but not enough rep :S